# Правильный join запрос в бд

Tags: php, pdo, join

Прошу помочь составить правильно запрос JOIN структуры.

1. Таблица spec (отсюда нужны id, inn, number, product поля)
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Таблица contract (отсюда мне нужен столбец shortname)
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура запроса:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM spec INNER JOIN contract ON (spec.inn = contract.inn)";
                        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        
                        $result = $stmt->fetchALL();
                        foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>" . $v['id'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $v['number'] . " от " . $v['date'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $v['shortname'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $v['product'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . ' <a href="eidtspec.php?inn=' . $v['inn'] . '">Редактировать</a></td>';
                        }
```

В результате я имею:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблема** в столбце ID, он не совпадает с значениями spec.id
В дальнейшем чтобы реализовать функционал редактирования / удаления спецификаций, я могу зацепиться только за id строки в таблице spec, все остальные данные могут частично повторяться.

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот запрос тебе должен помочь, ты выбираешь всё из обеих таблиц, так не желательно делать - id таблиц путаются, ну и все остальные столбцы таблиц

```
SELECT spec.*,contract.shortname FROM spec INNER JOIN contract ON spec.inn = contract.inn
```

Comment: спасибо, действительно, помогло)))